# Element() takes at most 3 positional arguments (10 given)

Tags: python-3.x, lxml

AM pretty new to xml generation using python. please guide to solve the issue.

I am trying to create a xml file as below usng lxml and python.

```
<StacksCollection>
<Stack ID="1" Name="flt_stack1" Size="1000000" Mode="E_CIRCULAR" OffBoardNotification="false" Counted="true" OffBoardNotifNoCtx="false" src="Editor" />
<Stack ID="2" Name="flt_stack2" Size="1000000" Mode="E_CIRCULAR" OffBoardNotification="false" Counted="true" OffBoardNotifNoCtx="false" src="Editor" />
<Stack ID="3" Name="flt_stack3" Size="1000000" Mode="E_CIRCULAR" OffBoardNotification="false" Counted="true" OffBoardNotifNoCtx="false" src="Editor" />
<Stack ID="4" Name="flt_stack4" Size="1000000" Mode="E_CIRCULAR" OffBoardNotification="false" Counted="true" OffBoardNotifNoCtx="false" src="Editor" />
</StacksCollection>
```

and my code as below

```
StacksCollection= ET.Element(Global_var_xmlWrite.Find_StackCollection)
for i in range(Global_var_xmlWrite.No_of_ID):
    StacksCollection.append(ET.SubElement(StacksCollection,Global_var_xmlWrite.Stack,Global_var_xmlWrite.ID[i],Global_var_xmlWrite.Name[i],Global_var_xmlWrite.Size[i],Global_var_xmlWrite.Mode[i],Global_var_xmlWrite.OffBoardNotification[i],Global_var_xmlWrite.Counted[i],Global_var_xmlWrite.OffBoardNotifNoCtx[i],Global_var_xmlWrite.src[i]))

templateXml.write(tostring((StacksCollection),pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=False, encoding='UTF-8').decode('utf-8'))
```

am getting error like  below

```
TypeError: SubElement() takes at most 4 positional arguments (10 given)
```

but i cant reduce the argument how can i overcome this error?

Comment: Why can't you reduce the number of arguments? What even are the arguments? `SubElement` accepts `parent`, `tag`, an `attrib` dict, and any number of _keyword_ arguments. Any extra positional arguments will produce an error, as they have no defined meaning. What did you intend to do?

Comment: I can't reduce because the tool which consumes this xml demanding it. Arguments are Id,Name,size,mode etc and so on as shown in xml... I trying to generate an xml like the one which I have posted in my question.

Comment: `ET.SubElement(StacksCollection, "Stack", { "ID": str(i), "Name": "flt_stack1", "Size": "1000000", "Mode": "E_CIRCULAR", "OffBoardNotification": "false", "Counted": "true", "OffBoardNotifNoCtx": "false", "src": "Editor" })` has only three parameters as required, produces the element you want, and - works. Note that `SubElement` already appends - you don't need `.append`.

Comment: Yup I tried by reducing the argument and xml generated properly. But I would like to know how can I code to contain 10 arguments in subelement.

Comment: I just showed you.

Comment: Thank you Amadan. I apologize for missed to notice  the answer you suggested me. Thanks a lot